# Cisco ASA Latency

Tags: cisco, cisco-asa, latency

What is the typical latency added when using a Cisco firewall such as ASA 5505? Are we talking less than 50 microseconds?

Comment: are you talking about microseconds or milliseconds?

Comment: Hmmm... could have *sworn* that question said "milliseconds" when I first read it.

Comment: Its pretty clear...microseconds.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The high-end Cisco ASA 5580 series has a published spec of 30μs latency as a selling point for ultra low-latency environments. The entry-level ASA 5505 would not be close to that level. I'd assume that 50μs is out of reach for the 5505.

Comment: Interesting...any idea where I can find out?

Answer (score 3):

I'm seeing about 3ms - 4ms between my web servers and my database servers for the TCP connection ( `SYN` -> `SYN/ACK` -> `ACK` ) traveling through an ASA 5510.

So yes, less than 50ms.

I don't know if the ASA 5505 is comparable.

For comparison, three TCP connections between two hosts on the same network that *didn't* travel through the ASA 5510 took 256μs when averaged.  (Same methodology as the first measurement.)

Comment: Are you measuring in milliseconds or microseconds?

Comment: @Ladadadada: Any chance you could show us your methodology for measuring this? I think that will be more useful in the long run to the world at whole than just the one sample..

Comment: ms is not microseconds - you're measuring milliseconds there. 1ms (millisecond) is equal to 1000  µs (microseconds).

Comment: I have an ASA 5505 and I see about 5 - 8 ms in the same metric @Ladadadada is describing.

Comment: ms is milliseconds. μs is microseconds.  I'm talking about milliseconds here.  My methodology was to fire up `tcpdump` and subtract the timestamp of the first packet *after* the three-way handshake from the timestamp of the first `SYN`.  I did this for three connections and averaged them.  (Hardly statistically significant, I know, but they were all very close to the same value.)

Comment: Obviously, that's also not measuring the latency of just the ASA 5510 but also everything else in the connection, including the load averages of both boxes.  It would be a valid answer when the question says "milliseconds" because it's significantly lower than 50, but it doesn't mean much when the question says "microseconds".

Comment: 5-8ms is no way correct...thats absolutely huge. I already have ping times with external servers of less than 1ms.

Comment: ICMP packets are not directly comparable to TCP handshakes.  There are also a lot of rules in this ASA which will increase the latency (how much? No idea) But I assure you that 3 - 4 ms is what I measured with the above method.